# How to produce 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am very new to Deep learning. I am working on the CIFAR10 dataset and created a CNN model which is as below.

```
class Net2(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net2, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5, 1)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 5 * 5, 512)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512,10)


  def forward(self, x):
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)),(2,2))
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x
    

net2 = Net2().to(device)
```

My assignment requirements are to create a model with:

Convolutional layer with 32 filters, kernel size of 5x5 and stride of 1.
Max Pooling layer with kernel size of 2x2 and default stride.
ReLU Activation Layers.
Linear layer with output of 512.
ReLU Activation Layers.
A linear layer with output of 10.

Which I guess I wrote. But I am assuming that I am going to the wrong path. Please help me to write the correct model and also the reason behind those arguments in Conv2d and Linear layers.

The error which I am getting from my code is as below:

```
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 3, 5, 5], but got 2-dimensional input of size [1024, 3072] instead
```

Please help me!

Comment: The issue is not with the model definition, but the input that you are passing to the model. Please show how you are doing that. The input size you are passing is apparently (1024,3072), while typically CIFAR10 inputs would be (B, 3, 32, 32), where B is the batch size.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thanks for the reply. But surprisingly I am not passing any values that can lead to the input size of (1024, 3072).

Comment: @GoodDeeds if i remove the piece of code from `forward` method which is `x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)` than the error message will change to : `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (458752x14 and 800x512)`

Comment: Please show a [mcve], there is not sufficient information to debug further. In particular, show how you create and pass the input.

Comment: @GoodDeeds There is nothing much to show. The assignment requirements says the output size and kernel size. The input size which I am using in first linear layer is the output of `self.conv1` which is 32 and trying to fit in the karnel size by 5 x 5. Altogether it will become 800 as input and 512 as output for Linear layer. Before the model I have loss function, optimizer, train,test,val (sets and loaders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code:

1. Flattening of input

   ```
   x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
   ```

   The convolutional layer expects a four dimensional input of dimensions (N, C, H, W), where N is the batch size, C = 3 is the number of channels, and (H, W) is the dimension of the image. By using the above statement, you are flattening your (1024, 3, 32, 32) input to (1024, 3072).
2. Number of input features in the first linear layer

   ```
   self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 5 * 5, 512)
   ```

   The output dimensions of the convolutional layer for a (1024, 3, 32, 32) input will be (1024, 32, 28, 28), and after applying the 2 x 2 maxpooling, it is (1024, 32, 14, 14). So the number of input features for the linear layer should be 32 x 14 x 14 = 6272.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And I am sorry to ask you again (I am very new to DL). How to solve the Flattering of input?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to solve the errors with your help. For Flattering the input I have used `x = torch.flatten(x, 1)` which is working just fine. I am getting maximum accuracy of `0.6598`. Thanks again.

Comment: @GamarChoba Not sure how that works. Maybe your input is formatted differently (you haven't shown that part of the code). Typically you do not need a flattening layer at all when passing an image input to a convolutional layer.